# Как массив вокселей разделить на части и получить одну из них по id?

Tags: c++, массивы, математика, графика, 3d

Есть массив вокселей xyz 16^3 (voxel - это short, пока так))), массив заполнен случайными short

```c++
short voxels[16][16][16]
```

Что хочу сделать:
Разделить  массив voxels на чанки по 4 * 8 * 8, взять чанк по id и вернуть vector вокселей в этом чанке
Для voxels[16][16][16] получилось бы 16 чанков по 4 * 8 * 8, один из этих чанков хочу получить по id и вернуть его воксели

Проблема с написанием этой функции:
*В функции учитываю что voxels может быть разного размера и чанки могут быть разного размера

```c++
// voxel_size = 16
// world_length = voxel_size = 16
vector<short> get_voxels_from_chunk(short (*voxels)[voxel_size][voxel_size][voxel_size], int world_length, int chunk_size_x, int chunk_size_y, int chunk_size_z, int chunk_id) {
    vector<short> result;
    int x_offset; // смещение чанка по x
    int y_offset; // смещение чанка по y
    int z_offset; // смещение чанка по z
    for (int i = x_offset; i < x_offset+chunk_size_x; i++){
        for (int ii = y_offset; ii < y_offset+chunk_size_y; ii++){
            for (int iii = z_offset; iii < y_offset+chunk_size_z; iii++){
                result.push_back(*voxels[i][ii][iii]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В чём именно проблема:
Не могу посчитать offset, как мне его посчитать?

Если интересно для чего это всё:
Хочу попробовать написать сжатие атрибутов вокселей, по плану: воксель - id в таблице с информацией о вокселе, поэтому это массив short (кстати до этого я не писал на с++)

Comment: Чтобы у куска был `id`, он должен быть уникальным. Каким образом его уникальность достигается? И почему у вас массив трёхмерный, а вектор одномерный? Ваш т.н. `offset` посчитать никак нельзя, функция просто не может знать, о том какой кусок вам сейчас нужен. Либо вам тогда нужен генератор (корутина), если вы хотите итерироваться через последовательные вызовы.

Comment: Вот такие функции с тысячей аргументов являются моветоном. Оборачивайте их во вспомогательные сущности. Передача размерностей массива может происходить через `NTTP`. Массивы можно передавать по ссылке.

Comment: @megorit, Спасибо за советы, поменял на передачу по ссылке, не знал как это делать). Кажется недостаточно понятно описал вопрос, извиняюсь за это. Ниже я добавил ответ с другого форума, возможно код будет понятнее моих слов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ с другого форума от автора Taulan Khatuaev
**Немного изменил его ответ, потому что недостаточно объяснил что хотел*

```c++
vector<short> get_voxels_from_chunk(
    short (&voxels)[voxel_size][voxel_size][voxel_size], int world_length,
    int chunk_size_x, int chunk_size_y, int chunk_size_z, int chunk_id
) {
    vector<short> result;

    int chunk_count_x = world_length / chunk_size_x;
    int chunk_count_y = world_length / chunk_size_y;
    int chunk_count_z = world_length / chunk_size_z;
    int chunk_index_x = chunk_id % chunk_count_x;
    int chunk_index_y = (chunk_id / chunk_count_x) % chunk_count_y;
    int chunk_index_z = chunk_id / (chunk_count_x * chunk_count_y);
    int x_offset = chunk_index_x * chunk_size_x;
    int y_offset = chunk_index_y * chunk_size_y;
    int z_offset = chunk_index_z * chunk_size_z;

    for (int i = x_offset; i < x_offset + chunk_size_x; i++)
        for (int ii = y_offset; ii < y_offset + chunk_size_y; ii++)
            for (int iii = z_offset; iii < z_offset + chunk_size_z; iii++)
                result.push_back(voxels[i][ii][iii]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Разве не видно, что `xoffset = 4*voxel_xpos` из имеющегося ответа то же самое, что `int x_offset = chunk_index_x * chunk_size_x;` ???

Comment: @MBo ну так у вас сплошной hardcode и magic numbers .. ;-) Этот ответ действительно получше.

Comment: @Kromster Ну так автор мог вступить в диалог и поинтересоваться, откуда что взялось

Comment: @MBo автор мог много чего (и даже решить вопрос в уме и не задавать его), так же как и вы (разжевать все и сопроводить картинками с сюжетом). ))

Answer (score 0):

```
xoffset = 4*voxel_xpos
yoffset = 2*voxel_ypos
zoffset = 2*voxel_zpos
```